# How Spring Boot decide the liveness state of the application?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

The [LivenessState](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/availability/LivenessState.java) of an application tells whether the internal state is valid. If Liveness is broken, this means that the application itself is in a failed state and cannot recover from it.

I would like to know what are the things that Spring Boot checks to decide the `Liveness` state.

Comment: Mister downvoter; I don't mind your downvote, just tell me what is it that you think is wrong with the question so I can make better ones in the future!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting from the official documentation of [Spring Boot Features](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-application-availability-liveness-state)

> The internal state of Spring Boot applications is mostly represented
>   by the Spring ApplicationContext. If the application context has
>   started successfully, Spring Boot assumes that the application is in a
>   valid state. An application is considered live as soon as the context
>   has been refreshed.
>
> In general, the "Liveness" state should not be based on external
>   checks, such as Health checks. If it did, a failing external system (a
>   database, a Web API, an external cache) would trigger massive restarts
>   and cascading failures across the platform.